# Red squiggles do not appear in VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, intellisense

I am using VS2008 pro and while autocomplete works properly I get that problem. My project is in visual c++/MFC and advanced settings are there for C#, but not for C/C++ as you can see below in order to enable them.

[image]

I figured out that it may be Intellisense that does not work properly, so have tried to clean my solution file and deleted .ncb and rebuild my project as others suggest, but without success. I have tried to create other projects, and the problem insists.
Finally, as an alternative I have found that I can use Virtual Assist, but this is the last choice for me.

So, how could I make red squiggles work again?

Comment: Try relaunching the visual studio again and build the project it should work. With the respect to virtual assist that is licensed i believe you can use max 30 days. Relaunching should work.

Comment: @Miank still nothing

Comment: C++ support in Visual Studio practically ended with Visual C++ 6 and was only re-introduced in Visual Studio 2010. If you want design-time support for C++, you're going to have to upgrade your IDE. Depending on the version you choose, you're getting better C++ but keep losing features in case you are using the graphical resource editor.

Comment: @Miank Still nothing. If  i make a syntax error the red squiggles do not appear neither advanced options. The build works properly though

Comment: @IInspectable I was thinking to upgrade it to VS2015 which I have, but the sln has 4 projects for windows mobile 5.0 pocket pc and when I am trying to migrate them I get error for some files project that are missing.

Comment: I would agree with @llnspectable start working on on different version of visual studio 2013 or 2015 if not a major constraint to work on 2008.

Comment: I remember that we had a hard time to migrate our VS2008 projects to VS2010. (In short: It simply didn't work.) We actually never fixed this. It appeared too tedious to me to re-create every project manually nor did we write our own migration. Actually, we switched to CMake, which made all the problems with VS project migration obsolete. Concerning Intellisense and C++, the first convincing version I saw in VS2013. In VS2008, I considered it rather as joke.

Comment: @Scheff I cannot change platform as the app I develop is for windows mobile 6. It seems that Visual Studio versions beyond Visual Studio 2008 no longer support Windows Mobile platforms.